# Extracting div attributes based on text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am using Python 3.6 with bs4 to implement this task.
my div tag looks like this

```
<div class="Portfolio" portfolio_no="345">VBHIKE324</div>
<div class="Portfolio" portfolio_no="567">SCHF54TYS</div>
```

I need to extract portfolio_no i.e 345. As it is a dynamic value it keeps changing for multiple div tags but whereas the text remains same.

```
for data in soup.find_all('div',class_='Portfolio', text='VBHIKE324'):
     print (data)
```

It outputs as None, where as I'm looking for o/p like 345

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
for data in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'Portfolio'}):
    print(data['portfolio_no'])
```

If you want the portfolio_no for the one with text `VBHIKE324` then you can do something like this

```
for data in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'Portfolio'}):
    if data.text == 'VBHIKE324':
        print(data['portfolio_no'])
```